# How to add new field in the repeatable if the current repeatable is not the first one in laravel nova

Tags: laravel-nova

I am developing a Web Application using Laravel Nova. And I want to add a new Number field in the repeatable, if the current repeatable count is greater than 1.

Tried to access the index but didn't worked.

I'm using laravel 9 and laravel-nova 4.+.